# Applescript to update year tag for audio files

Tags: applescript, script, mp3, id3-tag

I have a lot of tracks in iTunes where the files are named "music-NNNN.mp3" with NNNN being the year the track was recorded. How can I use Applescript to automatically set the year tag for these files based on NNNN?

Comment: What have you tried? I am sure someone will help fine tune script that is not currently working.

Comment: Also look at [Doug's Applescripts for iTunes](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/) there will be one to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created an AppleScript for you that will parse the filenames of any selected iTunes tracks and set the year tag accordingly.

Paste this into **AppleScript Editor** and run it (or save it as an application):

```
tell application "iTunes"
    repeat with theTrack in selection
        set theFile to location of theTrack
        tell application "Finder" to set theName to name of theFile
        set theYear to my parse_year(theName)
        if theYear is not "" then
            set the year of theTrack to theYear
        end if
    end repeat
end tell

on parse_year(filenameText)
    -- returns the year if it exists in filename with form song-1965.mp3, else returns empty string
    try
        set yearResult to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of filenameText & " | perl -ne 'print $1 if s/(?<=-)(\\d+)(?=(\\..*|$))/$1/'"
    on error
        set yearResult to ""
    end try
    return yearResult
end parse_year
```

A few notes:

- It doesn't go through the whole library, only the currently selected songs (you can of course select your whole library).
- It only matches filenames with that end with a `-` followed by a number (and optionally an extension).

  - It will match these:

    ```
    songname-1946.mp3
    anothersong-1977
    songname-1965.someextention
    ```
  - But not these:

    ```
    songnoyear.mp3
    song123
    song-1232-someothertext
    ```
- It will overwrite any year already entered in the metadata.

Comment: The -P option (for Perl regex) was removed in 10.8.

Comment: Good catch. I updated it to just use Perl directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
set text item delimiters to {"-", "."}
tell application "iTunes"
    repeat with t in selection
        set year of t to text item -2 of (location of t as text)
    end repeat
end tell
```

Unlike many other [command line utilities for changing ID3 tags](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3585/is-there-a-good-command-line-id3-tool-for-os-x), mid3v2 supports both Unicode and ID3v2.

```
sudo easy_install pip
sudo pip install mutagen
for f in */*.mp3; do y=${f%##*/}; y=${y%.mp3}; /usr/local/bin/mid3v2 -y ${y#*-} "$f"; done
```

You can also use [TriTag](http://www.feedface.com/projects/tritag.html) for changing tags based on file names or vice versa.