# Applescript to update MP3 Spotlight tag from iTunes tag

Tags: itunes, finder, applescript, spotlight, mp3

Here is my situation. I have a large iTunes library that has songs tagged with the "Year" in iTunes.  I have a Hazel Rule for the noodlesoft hazel software which reads from Finder's "Year Recorded" metatag.  I would like an applescript that can recursively for all tracks selected read the iTunes "Year" track and embed it into the file's "Year Recorded" metadata so Finder/Spotlight will then see that information.  I saw this: [Applescript to update year tag for audio files](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75362/applescript-to-update-year-tag-for-audio-files) but it is not what I need.  Any help on this would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if one exists specifically for that case, but as a general rule of thumb, if it can be done, it will be on [Doug's Applescripts](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/)